# Spring boot eagerly initialize some beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to enable lazy initialization for my spring boot application to improve the startup time.
But once I do that this causes some problems. E.g. my KafkaListeners are also not initialized and will not receive any messages.
Can I enable lazy initialization, but eagerly initialize some specific beans?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to make a specific bean eager initialized, I found the annotation org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy(false). This made it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

By default all beans are initialized eagerly in order to have consistent application context. You could initialize some specific beans lazily with `@Lazy`.

Comment: I enabled lazy initialization by adding this to my configuration:

spring.main.lazy-initialization: true

This is not the problem. Problem was to get specific beans to be eager.